# TomEE | CDI - Fat JAR deployment incompatible with managed bean lifecycles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, apache-tomee, fatjar

I run my TomEE in a Fat JAR type of deployment, and I recently noticed that my `@PreDestroy` lifecycle was not being triggered when interrupted (`^C` signal). I believe this may be due to the fact that when the Fat JAR explodes into the WAR, the WAR will be run in a separate JVM. I have noticed that if I configure my own shutdown hook, it will indeed trigger.

Application.java

```java
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class Application {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("=============INITIALIZING=============");
        Runtime.getRuntime()
                .addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Shutdown Hook is running!")));
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void deinit() {
        System.out.println("=============DESTROYING===============");
    }
}
```

But, this is not the end-all solution, as I still have untouched lifecycles. Spring Boot handles this quite well with their Fat JAR's with its preconfigured [shutdown hook](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-exit). Code for it can be seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#L989-L1043).

I am hoping that a TomEE Dev can chime in on this issue. Currently, I see anyone who is using Fat JAR's to be prone to this issue unless they have coded their own managed bean shutdown hook.